# Create javascript document from xmldocument

Tags: javascript, xmldocument, samsung-smart-tv

I've been using $.ajax() to get some data from a server but due to incompatibility with previous version of my system (samsung smart tv) I have had to implement XMLHttpRequest also. My problem is that with jQuery, the responseXML returns a [object Document] while XMLHttpRequest's responseXML returns a [object XMLDocument]. Since I already had everything implemented using Documents, is there a way to parse a XMLDocument object or a string object into a Document?

Any help is appreciated, I'm stuck here and don't want to rewrite everything for XMLDocument.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your response explicitly stating it is xml? can you not just get the response to say its plain text? Or at least something along those lines.

Comment: yep, is explicitly asking for xml in both cases. Actually they receiving the same HTTP 200 ok response from the server. I guess I could get the response as a text also, but then again I would have to change everything.

Comment: What i meant is the server side, is that explicitly setting the document response type to xml? if it is, do you have access to the server side code and could you possibly set this to another response type?

Comment: I guess the server is setting the response to xml, but don't know for sure, I don't have access to the server

Comment: I'm getting this as a response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and then a SOAP message

Comment: Ah ok, in that case I'm not really sure, I hardly ever deal with XMLHttpRequest.  Is there not a way to convert XMLDocument to Document?

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do but with no success... I'll keep trying, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to responseXML, you should also have a responseText property coming from XMLHttpRequests. I'm using the following [in a similar way](https://github.com/Incrediberry/jsberry/blob/master/libs/Namespace.class.js).

```
xhrObj.open('GET', scriptURL, false);
xhrObj.send('');
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.type = "text/javascript";
se.text = xhrObj.responseText;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);
```

Comment: But this doesnt return document... it returns a HTMLScriptObject. Is there a way to create a document?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that diferent browsers return diferent things but in the end is the same.